# How to calculate first three orders of PACF function given ARMA model?

Tags: self-study, arima, autocorrelation, arma

Is there a way to calculate the first three orders (i.e. $\phi_{11}$ $\phi_{22}$, and $\phi_{33}$) of PACF given the estimated form of ARMA model, for example:

$Y_t=-0,7Y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t-0,7\varepsilon_{t-1}$